# How does Find method of Entity Framework work?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am learning Entity Framework and faced some moment with **Find()** method I can't understand.
*Sample taken from book of Julia Lerman "Programming Entity Framework : Code First"*

```
public class Destination
{
    public int DestinationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public byte?[]  Photo { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Lodging> Lodgings { get; set; }

    public Destination()
    {
        Lodgings = new List<Lodging>();
    }
}

public class Lodging
{
    public int LodgingId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public bool IsResort { get; set; }
    public Destination Destination { get; set; }
}
```

And I operate with the data in the following ways :

```
var destination = organizationDbContext.Destinations // case # 1
                .Include("Lodgings")
                .First(p=>p.DestinationId==1); 

var destination = organizationDbContext.Destinations.Find(1); // case # 2
```

1. Why I can't call Find() method in the first case after Include() call, but can use Where() and First()?
2. If I use second case with Find(), here I can't call Include() method to Lodgings, so how should I load related lodgings?

My questions could be expressed in another way:

1. What is the right way to do : find one object and load all related inner objects (one-to-many)?
2. What is the right way to do : load all objects (set A) and inner related objects (set A.I) , then find one by id from (A)?

Comment: As far as i know `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't contain method `Find` but `DbSet<T>` does. That's why it is there in case #2

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The point is that `Find` starts by searching in the local cache of the context. If no match are found then it sends a query to the db.

> The Find method on DbSet uses the primary key value to attempt to find
>   an entity tracked by the context. If the entity is not found in the
>   context then a query will be sent to the database to find the entity
>   there. Null is returned if the entity is not found in the context or
>   in the database.

I think it's the inner explanation that there is no `Find` on IQueryable.
When you are using the following code EF send always a request to the db:

```
var destination = organizationDbContext.Destinations // case # 1
                .Include("Lodgings")
                .First(p=>p.DestinationId==1);
```

More infos : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj573936.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that we use different types and one of this types contains method Find while another one doesn't :

1.

```
var destination = organizationDbContext.Destinations // case # 1
                .Include("Lodgings") // type here is IQueryable<T> no method Find defined
                .First(p=>p.DestinationId==1);
```

2.

```
                                     // type here is DbSet<T> with defined method Find
var destination = organizationDbContext.Destinations.Find(1);
```

Comment: This seems to be a new question. At any rate, it's not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

1- **Find method** in Entity Framework is typically used with the *primary key*, and it doesn't accept a lambda expression.
var destination = _context.Destinations.Find(promoContent.Id);

2- If you need to use a **condition other than the primary key** for the retrieval, you should use the *FirstOrDefault or SingleOrDefault*
var destination = _context.Destinations.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id==promoContent.Id
// && x.Name == "jack" // this is optional//
);

Comment: Yeah, but that's not the key difference, which was sufficiently explained in the accepted answer.